# How would I convert this formula in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How would I combine the contents of both D and C in the same cell?

The formula is:

```
=QUERY(courtdates,"SELECT D, C, AQ WHERE BM = date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)
```

Comment: Same cell means what? Where do you want to show result?

Comment: I want to show the results of this in 2 cells, whereby the first cell contains D+C, and the second cell contains AQ.

Comment: Further to that, let's say D = Apple, C = Tree, AQ = Shoe, I want one cell to say "Apple Tree," and the second cell to say "Shoe"

Comment: Then you need two formula for two separate cell. `=D1 & " " C1` and  `=AQ`.

Comment: If the answer below is not working for you can you provide a sheet with example data? Otherwise, be sure to accept the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=QUERY(
  {
    INDEX(courtdates_sheets!D:D & " " & courtdates_sheets!C:C),
    courtdates_sheets!AQ:AQ,
    courtdates_sheets!BM:BM
  },
  "SELECT Col1, Col2
   WHERE Col3 = date '" & TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'",
)
```

Where `courtdates_sheets` is the sheet name where *courtdates* named range is defined.